# How can React Native access the iOS dictionary to pull the definition of a word?

Tags: ios, reactive-programming

It looks like there is some reference in Apple's documentation, but I don't see this in any components (listed here for example).

Because this seems like a pretty standard feature, I feel like I'm just missing something basic. It's also not the easiest thing to search for.

Here is Apple's sdk documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIReferenceLibraryViewControllerClassRef/index.html

Answer (score 5):

As you already know, to be able to use native code you'll need to create a native module.

Here's how..

**Start by adding a new file in Xcode**:

File > New File > Cocoa Touch Class.
Make sure you set it as a subclass of NSObject. Name it ReferenceLibraryManager for example.

**In the header file (.h):**

You simply need to implement the `RCTBridgeModule` protocol:

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface ReferenceLibraryManager : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

**In the method file (.m):**

You'll need to implement and expose a native method that you can call from your JS like so:

```
#import "ReferenceLibraryManager.h"
#import <UIKit/UIReferenceLibraryViewController.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ReferenceLibraryManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(showDefinitionForTerm:(NSString*)term callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  if (callback == nil)
    return;

  BOOL hasDefinition = NO;
  if ([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:term])
  {
    hasDefinition = YES;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      UIReferenceLibraryViewController *referenceLibraryVC = [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:term];
      UIViewController *rootVC = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window.rootViewController;
      [rootVC presentViewController:referenceLibraryVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
  }

  callback(@[@(hasDefinition)]);
}

@end
```

**Some interesting things to notice:**

1. To be able to present a "view controller" like we're doing here, you need another view
   controller to present it. The code above does that using the
   "root view controller" of the app. It's supposed to work for most
   cases but it also depends on the structure of your app.
2. React native will not call the native component methods on the main thread. When handling anything related to UI you must do it on the main thread, hence to usage of `dispatch_async` to the main thread.

**The JavaScript part:**

You import your native module and just use it..

```
var React = require('react-native');
var ReferenceLibraryManager = React.NativeModules.ReferenceLibraryManager;
....
var term = "React";
ReferenceLibraryManager.showDefinitionForTerm(term, (hasDefinition) => {

  if(!hasDefinition) {
    alert('definition not found...');
  }
})
```

By the way - you can find the complete guide and example for creating native modules on the [react native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content).

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I will comment/vote back when I give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code, but every word is returning no definition :(

Comment: @kevando Well, that's not a problem with the code, is it? :) You probably don't have any dictionaries defined if you're working with the simulator. You'll need to add dictionaries using the "manage" button on the bottom toolbar of the dictionary screen (the screen which shows "no definition found").

Comment: Awesome! This works now @Artal I assume getting the definition data into my app as JSON is going to be straight forward now.

Comment: Reading here, it seems there might not actually be a way to get the definition data?! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIReferenceLibraryViewControllerClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIReferenceLibraryViewController/initWithTerm:

Comment: @kevando I thought it was obvious... This only displays the definition with Apple's UI. As far as I know there's no way to get a definition without showing the UIReferenceLibraryViewController. You can always find an external library that can do this or use an online service.

Comment: I currently use an online API, but I hoped my app could function 100% offline. Oh well, at least I know how to build native modules!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still need this functionality. I've written a [npm package](https://github.com/jktzes/react-native-reference-library-view) for doing just that(Thanks, [Artal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33816753/9182558)).

A quick demo is given below.

[image: a simple demo]

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps you

```
NSString *str =@"pretty";
// pass word as string in str which you want to search
if ([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:str]) {
    UIReferenceLibraryViewController* ref =
    [[UIReferenceLibraryViewController alloc] initWithTerm:str];
    [self presentViewController:ref animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    // do something when no definition found
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sp309 for this answer. Could you help me bridge the gap to react-native? I've never developed native iOS either, so it's this bridge that I have trouble with.